# Installing EBGaramond fonts for CentOS 6

Tags: fonts, ebgaramond

I'm having trouble getting the ebgaramond fonts to work under CentOS 6.  Any advice about how to track down the problem would be appreciated.

I've downloaded the ebgaramond fonts from CTAN:
https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ebgaramond?lang=en
and installed the files by sorting the .sty file and various font files into what seem to be appropriate locations (I'll append my texmf.cnf file below, in case that helps).

I test it with this latex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\begin{document}
Hello World!
\end{document}
```

and get the following output:

```
This is pdfTeXk, Version 3.141592-1.40.3 (Web2C 7.5.6)
 %&-line parsing enabled.
entering extended mode
(./junk.tex
LaTeX2e <2005/12/01>
Babel <v3.8h> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, arabic, basque, bulgarian, coptic, welsh, czech, slovak, german, ng
erman, danish, esperanto, spanish, catalan, galician, estonian, farsi, finnish,
 french, greek, monogreek, ancientgreek, croatian, hungarian, interlingua, ibyc
us, indonesian, icelandic, italian, latin, mongolian, dutch, norsk, polish, por
tuguese, pinyin, romanian, russian, slovenian, uppersorbian, serbian, swedish, 
turkish, ukenglish, ukrainian, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2005/09/16 v1.4f Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/common/lib/texmf/tex/latex/ebgaramond/latex/ebgaramond.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/home/bkw1a/tex/ifluatex.sty) (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/xkeyval/keyval.tex)))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/common/lib/texmf/tex/latex/fontaxes/fontaxes.sty)) (./junk.aux)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(/common/lib/texmf/tex/latex/ebgaramond/latex/OT1EBGaramond-OsF.fd) [1{/var/lib
/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./junk.aux)kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 0+500/600 --dpi 500 EBGaramond12-Regular-osf-ot1
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for EBGaramond12-Regular-osf-ot1.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
 )

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file EBGaramond12-Regular-osf-ot1): Font EBGaramond12
-Regular-osf-ot1 at 500 not found
Output written on junk.pdf (1 page, 1049 bytes).
Transcript written on junk.log.
```

The font files from the CTAN zip file have been moved to /common/lib/texmf/fonts/enc, .../map, .../opentype, .../tfm, .../type1, and .../vf.  The /common/lib/texmf tree is (I think!) being searched, based on my texmf.cnf file.

Running strace on the mktexpk command (from missingfonts.log), I see that it's calling:

```
kpsewhich EBGaramond12-Regular-osf-ot1.mf
```

which returns nothing, because the ebgaramond zip file doesn't contain any mf files.

Here's the texmf.cnf file, in pastebin: https://pastebin.com/pjXfqy9q

Comment: You should either install the package with your package manager or command line or install the fonts and use `xelatex` or `lualatex`.

Comment: Have you considered ditching your distro's TeX Live and installing from upstream? Then you'll get `ebgaramond` as part of a standard installation. @Joseph On CentOS?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I have a department full of these and I don't want to make major changes to the installed tex system just for the sake of adding some fonts.   Unfortunately, I haven't found any packages that install the fonts.  @Joseph , do you know of any?

Comment: @BryanWright, you have to check your system's Latex distro has the package. I don't know CentOS, so I can't help you there. Otherwise, just download the fonts from the Internet (http://www.georgduffner.at/ebgaramond/)  and compile with `xelatex` and the package `fontspec` to use the fonts. It's painless -- unless you don't have `xelatex` or `fontspec` either, in case I would really suggest you to upgrade your TeX Live.

Comment: @BryanWright any updates here?

Comment: Sorry, no updates.  I've moved on to CentOS 7, which includes ebgaramond by default.